# SQL how do i find only those tuples in table 1 that match all tuples in table 2?

Tags: sql

I'm stuck on a SQL query assignment.

The question is to find the organization names of the organizations that have all europeans countries with over 50 million inhabitants as a member.

**isMember**

**Country** - **Organization** - **Type**

TL      - ACD          - Member

AL - ACD - Member

**Organization**

**abbreviation** - **name** - **city**

C - Commonwealth - London

D - Group of 10 - London

These are the two tables that i think i will need. There are some more that I've used to determine the population and whether the country is in Europe that I've used.

So far i've come to this

```
SELECT country.name, country.code FROM population, country, encompasses WHERE     country.code=encompasses.country AND encompasses.continent='Europe' AND country.code=population.country AND country.population>=50000000
```

The result of this query is:

```
      name      | code 
----------------+------
France         | F
Germany        | D
Italy          | I
Ukraine        | UA
Russia         | R
Turkey         | TR
United Kingdom | GB
```

So the question is how do i check if a organization has the countries above as members?

Comment: so, where is the table that shows what countries belong to an organization?

Comment: isMember has a column named Country that has the country code. This country code is equivalent to the code column in my current query.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
SELECT
        Name
FROM Organization O
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
            1
    FROM isMember M
    JOIN Country C ON M.Country = C.Code
    JOIN Encompasses E ON E.Country = M.Country
    WHERE
            M.Type = 'Member'
        AND
        (
            C.Population < 50000001
        OR
            E.Continent <> 'Europe'
        )
)
```